# innerText and CSS content:before

Tags: javascript, css, microsoft-edge, innertext

I am trying to find out if `content` in a `::before` selector changes the parent's innerText in any browser. I have tested in Chrome and Safari so far, and it doesn't change the innerText in either

```js
document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(function() {
  this.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.target.classList.toggle("Completed");
  });
});

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(testUL.innerText);
});
```

```css
    li.Completed:before {
      content: "\2713";
      color: green;
      background: #ffdf87;
    }
```

```html
<ul id="testUL">
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul>

<button id="test">Test innerText</button>
```

This is good for my purposes (I am trying to match documents by text only). But from what I read on Mozilla, it seems like maybe this is incorrect behavior?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Can anyone test this snippet I've posted here and confirm if similar behavior occurs in MS Edge?

Comment: Why do you believe that excluding pseudo-element content from `innerText` is incorrect behavior? What part of the documentation contradicts the observed behavior? It says _“Value: A DOMString representing the rendered text content of an element.”_ — Note that pseudo-elements are neither elements nor nodes. The [specification](//html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute) is consistent with the observed behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes same behaviour in MS Edge (Windows10).

This is as expected. The content of the pseudo element can be seen, but it not a 'proper' part of the page, hence the word 'pseudo'.

It is basically there for visual effect rather than 'real' content. For example, normally screen readers won't take any notice of it.

Comment: Thank you for this! In particular, the information about the impact of this on screen readers is very useful and has me thinking about how I could make my product and styles more accessible to all